# Drawing a Line to the Midpoint of a Custom Shape in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-shape

I have defined a custom shape called `myBOX` using `\pgfdeclareshape`. My objective is to draw a line from point `(0,0)` to `(0,2)` and connect it to the midpoint of the left-hand side line of the node `myBOX`. Please find my **CODE**, **OUTPUT** and **desired OUTPUT** provided below.

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
    
\pgfdeclareshape{myBOX}{
    
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    
    \savedanchor\PinA{\pgfpoint{0}{10}}
    \anchor{PINA}{\PinA}
    
    \foregroundpath{        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{\pgfpoint{30}{20}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    }
}

\begin{document} 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw (0,0)--(2,0) node[myBOX, red] {};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**desired OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Change,  \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}, to,   \anchor{center}{\pgfpoint{0}{10}}, otherwise your anchor goes to {0}{0} (the origin)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To Paul A:

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfdeclareshape{myBOX}{
    
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpoint{0}{10}} %% <- Solution (Thanks to Paul A)
    
    \savedanchor\PinA{\pgfpoint{0}{10}}
    \anchor{PINA}{\PinA}
    
    \foregroundpath{        
        \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}{\pgfpoint{30}{20}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    }
}

\begin{document} 
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw (0,0)--(2,0) node[myBOX, red] {};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]